# Clean the cache of iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser-cache

I have an erroneous html+javascript. It returns a `Uncaught ReferenceError: number is not defined`, which is expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
   <html>
   <body>
     <p id="demo"></p>
     <script>
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number();
     </script>
     <script id="jsbin-javascript">
       function number() {
        return 1;
       }
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

However, if I run the code as a string by `iframe` **twice** ([plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/IVFVtvJQCmE68yJ98IWS?p=preview)), the second run oddly returns a result. It is because the `number` function is cached somewhere by the first run, which is not what I want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe></iframe>

    <script>
          var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
          var iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument; 
          iframe_doc.open();
          iframe_doc.write(source);
          iframe_doc.close();

          var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
          var iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument;
          iframe_doc.open();
          iframe_doc.write(source);
          iframe_doc.close();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So does anyone know how to clean the cache, such that each run of `iframe` is completely a new one?

**Edit 1** Following the answer of @LeonidVasilyev, I have added in html:

```
<section id="output">
  <iframe></iframe>
</section>
```

And in JavaScript of my playground:

```
this.render = function (code) {

    var source = prepareSource(code);

    var placeholder = document.getElementById("output");
    while (placeholder.firstChild) {
        placeholder.removeChild(placeholder.firstChild);
    }
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    placeholder.appendChild(iframe); 

    var iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument;
    iframe_doc.open();
    iframe_doc.write(source);
    iframe_doc.close();
}
```

What is odd is that, **every time I reload/refresh the page, the paper icon in the Chrome tab and the reload round icon each flash twice**. It is because of `placeholder.appendChild(iframe)`, because if i remove this line, it flashes once.

Does anyone know how to avoid this icon twice-flashing?

[image]

Comment: Euh, not sure if I understand correctly. But you can fix `Uncaught ReferenceError: number is not defined` by just putting the function inside the same script tag as the call to it. So what are you trying to do with the iframe? Is it just a fix for the above error? Or do you actually need an iframe for something?

Comment: Also, the reason why you need to call the iframe code twice is because the iframe and the parent frame aren't in sync. SO when you try to write to the body of the iframe, the DOM isn't loaded yet, so you need to setTimeout the doc.write.

Comment: I am doing a playground with iframe, so when a code is supposed to return an error, the playground should return an error. But what I realise is that when i write iframe several times, it makes erroneous code run, because of cache (this is my guess), so i want to clean the cache...

Comment: Iframe and the parent frame DO NOT share state and document. If you would write `var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
setTimeout(function() { var iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument;  iframe_doc.open(); iframe_doc.write(source); iframe_doc.close();
}, 10);` is will probably work as well. So why try to fix something that isn't broken? Iframe is probably not the tech you want to use if you want to do alot of stuff with the playground inside the frame.

Comment: If we don't use iframe, what could be alternative for the output of my playground?

Comment: Depends on what that playground is. If it's just a script that generates some html with events bound to it, why not insert it into a div on the parent page? If it's an external page though, you'll need the iframe indeed, but then it's probably cross-domain, which will give you alot of issues with communicating with the iframe.

Comment: my goal is to make a complete playground, as complete as jsbin and plunker. Do they use iframes or some better means?

Comment: I think they just use a basic page and have the server side generate a new version every time you fork the 'playground'. Not sure what they would need an iframe for, since you only really need an iframe to embed pages NOT under your control and some cross domain hacks. Plunkr does use an iframe, since it fully embeds the page you write into an output, but apart from that, I don't think there's any other interaction between the two windows. Also, they definately won't use globals, which fixes the number() already defiend issue.

Answer (score 0):

That is a Chrome [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=149785). In your case `document.open()` must create new global object. Excerpt from [description of document.open() algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-document-open) in HTML specification:

> 16. Call the JavaScript InitializeHostDefinedRealm() abstract operation with the following customizations:
>
>     - For the global object, **create a new Window object window**.
>     - For the global this value, use the current browsing context's
>         associated WindowProxy.
>     - Let realm execution context be the created JavaScript execution
>         context.

Firefox 51 and Internet Explorer 11 properly create new `Window` object.

As a workaround you can create new `iframe` node on each iteration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <script>
      var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");
      var iframe = null;

      iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
      placeholder.appendChild(iframe);
      var iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument;
      iframe_doc.open();
      iframe_doc.write(source);
      iframe_doc.close();

      iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
      placeholder.appendChild(iframe);
      var iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument;
      iframe_doc.open();
      iframe_doc.write(source);
      iframe_doc.close();  
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see... one remark about `placeholder.appendChild(iframe);` is that, every time I refresh the page, I see the icône in Chrome tab flashes. It is a very small thing because of `appendChild`, I don't know why...

Comment: As I am doing a playground, that means each time we modify the code, we have to remove the existing iframe and append a new iframe, that seems to me too frequent manipulations of DOM, no? is there any alternatives?

Comment: Although this is correct, it's a side effect from the iframe DOM. Since you can't just iframe.onload (wont work in all browsers), you don't know when the iframe document can be accessed, hence it only works the second time. (the iframe had time to load) And the number already beign defined is a side effect of using globals. If the function was not a global inside the iframe, you won't have to do the whole create new iframe node thingy.

Comment: I checked HTML specification and it looks like it's a Chrome bug.

Comment: I added link to Chromium issue to my answer.

Comment: Good to know it is a bug, and i don't think they will fix it soon, so i have to use the workaround. Please see my update...